# Angular 6 proxy file is not loading

Tags: angular, proxy, angular-cli

proxy.conf.json file is created and located at root. Right next to package.json

### proxy.conf.json:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://localhost:5001",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

### package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

The error that is returned is a 404 not found. The requests are still going to the front end server.

Is there anything else I have to configure in the angular.json file?
+I have added an entry to angular.json file `"proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"`

The error I am getting in Angular console is `[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /users from localhost:4200 to https://localhost:5001 (UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)`

I also tried using npm start. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My back-end server running is ASP.NET Core which runs localhost over HTTPS. My proxy file was suggesting that this was a secure connection, but changing the secure option to false, and removing the pathRewrite option, I was successfully able to reach my back-end end point.